# How to catch a 'Visual C++ Debug Assertial failed!' gracefully

Tags: c#, c++, .net, exception, assertions

I have a C# application, that works with Windows Shared Memory.  Sometimes when you called the shared memory functions out-of-order (or a handful of other calls), you can get a 'Debug Assertion Failed!' error.

[image]

My question: Is there any way I can do something like fire off an event when this happens, so I can log some info?  I'd like to do anything besides what it does, which is cause my application to crash, and not allow me to execute any code at all.

Comment: There's nothing graceful about this, it is a gross bug in your code.  The show is over when it fires, you have to fix this.

Comment: Yes, your program is already screwed, just be grateful that you were told.  There is no logical path but to crash.